# Showing $e^{-x^2/n^2}$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = e^{-(x/n)^2}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,4]$.

It obvious to see that $f_n \to e^0 = 1$ pointwise.

Now we must just show that $$\|f_n(x) - 1\|_{\sup} \to 0$$ I have that $$\|f_n(x) - 1\|_{\sup} = \sup_{x\in [0,4]} |e^{-(x/n)^2} - 1| = |e^{-(16/n^2)} -1| \to 0$$ Is this all, or have I misunderstood the defintiion of uniform convergence

Comment: your solution is true.

Answer (score 0):

Show $limit_{n->+∞ }$$\sup_{x\in [0,4]} |e^{-(x/n)^2} - 1|$ = 0 <=> $f_n$ converges to 1 uniformly. Please note that "<=>" is necessary and sufficient condition.